# JUnit saying test failed. See difference say content is identical

Tags: junit, intellij-idea, assert

JUnit  is saying that the test failed. However when I press the see difference link it reveals that the content is identical. So why is the test failing if the two objects are the same?

**The test I am running.**

```
 Assert.assertSame(card,vCardService.DecodeVCard(text));
```

**This is displayed when I press the "see difference" link**

[image]

**Error.**

```
 Expected :Card [CardId=1, UserId=0, FirstName=Joel, LastName=Dean,     WorkNumber=18769023684, CellNumber=18765757810, Email=jdeanjj1000@gmail.com, Title=Mr., UserProfileImageUrl=null, CompanyName=Xormis, CompanyAddress=null, CompanyLatitude=0.0, CompanyLongitude=0.0, LogoUrl=null, QrCodeUrl=null, QrVCardUrl=null, VCardUrl=null, FacebookUrl=null, Website=null, ShareCount=0]
Actual   :Card [CardId=1, UserId=0, FirstName=Joel, LastName=Dean, WorkNumber=18769023684, CellNumber=18765757810, Email=jdeanjj1000@gmail.com, Title=Mr., UserProfileImageUrl=null, CompanyName=Xormis, CompanyAddress=null, CompanyLatitude=0.0, CompanyLongitude=0.0, LogoUrl=null, QrCodeUrl=null, QrVCardUrl=null, VCardUrl=null, FacebookUrl=null, Website=null, ShareCount=0]
 <Click to see difference>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotSame(Assert.java:737)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertSame(Assert.java:680)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertSame(Assert.java:691)
    at com.grikly.app.test.VCardServiceTest.testDecodeVCard(VCardServiceTest.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:76)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Answer (score 4):

You want assertEquals; assertSame if they are the same object.

Comment: Um, have you overrode equals.Bit clueless if this isn't the answer

Comment: The problem was that I was comparing two objects. Although they contain the same information they are different in nature so I think that's what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but while comparing 2 String objects (!!!).
Turns out IntelliJ is not so smart if you use

assertThat(X, is(Y));

It will not show you the difference between '\n' and '\n' - even though it is there.
I can recommand using assertEquals() instead, then it will be painfully obvious where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ will tell you "Contents are identical" even if the two strings differ by style of line endings. For example, if the actual string has Unix-style endings and the expected string has Windows-style endings, IntelliJ will show "Contents are identical" but the assertion will fail.